# Matlab function working only in debug mode

Tags: matlab

I have a function in a separate file

```
   function [ ] = loadModel( model , version )

   cd(model.path);  

   loadPath =  strcat(model.name(1,:) , model.versions(version,:), '_results' ) ;

   load(loadPath,'-mat');

   end
```

which using model structure and version number as inputs changes directory to the one of the model and loads its results. When I call the function from a m-file there is no error but its seems like none of the lines of the function have been executed e.g. a variable loadPath doesn't even exist. When I put a break point before load(), I see loadPath generated correctly and if I type the last line manually it works fine. Any clues why is this happening?

P.S. I am used to C++, Java and I find the matlab language absolute nighmare

Answer (score 2):

This is because you're only loading the file within the scope of the `loadModel` function. In MATLAB, variables declared within a function (this includes through file loading) are *only* defined within that function (barring global variables, `assignin`, etc). You need to return the results of the file load in order to use the loaded data. For instance:

```
function data = loadModel( model , version )

cd(model.path);  

loadPath =  strcat(model.name(1,:) , model.versions(version,:), '_results' ) ;

data = load(loadPath,'-mat');

end
```

This will load the file into a struct, which is returned to the calling scope. You can then access the loaded data from this struct.

Comment: What if I don't want my function to return anything. What if I don't want to think about what every single function should return, but instead want whatever is being done by this function to be done to the workspace from which it was called???

Comment: You've got a few options. The easiest is the one I've suggested. Failing that, you could use a script file, which is just a collection of commands which will be run in the current workspace - the main problem with this is that you can't pass arguments to a script file like you can a function file. Alternatively, you could play around with `evalin` or `assignin`, though I would strongly suggest against this. Finally, you could define the variables as `global`, which will make the accessible from every workspace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the concept of workspace: the function workspace is different from the base workspace (the one you can access from the command line). Your function executes normally and the variable `loadPath` is created, but in the function workspace, not the base workspace. As your function doesn't return anything you don't have access to it. In debug mode, you get access to the function workspace, so you can see the variable. You need the function to return the variable of interest if you want to access it from the base workspace. I suggest you have a look at the documentation, it's very thorough.